# Why is the performance of Apache Spark worse than R on a local cluster?

Tags: r, performance, sorting, apache-spark

I am comparing the performance of R and Apache Spark on a local machine and R seems to be doing much better. Is that because I am not using a cluster or am I doing something wrong?

**Create data (create_data.R):**

```
options = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
rows = as.numeric(options[1])

perday = 365 / (rows-1) * 6
dates = seq(as.Date('2010-01-01'), as.Date('2015-12-31'), by=perday)
rows = length(dates)
ids = sample(paste0("ID", seq(1:10000)), rows, replace=TRUE)
sales = rpois(rows,50)
categories = sample(paste("Category", sprintf("%02d",seq(1:10))), rows, replace=TRUE)
data = data.frame(dates, ids, sales, categories)

write.csv(data, "/home/phil/performance/data.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

**Test R (cut.R):**

```
suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(require(dplyr, quietly=TRUE)))

data = read.csv("data.csv")
first_purchase = head(data[order(data$dates, data$ids),],1)

print(first_purchase)
```

**Test Spark (cut.py):**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local")

rdd = sc.textFile("data.csv", 2)

# Get rid of header
header = rdd.take(1)[0]
rdd = rdd.filter(lambda line: line != header)

rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
first_purchase = rdd.takeOrdered(1, lambda x: [x[0],x[1]])[0]
print(first_purchase)
```

**Run complete test (run_tests.sh):**

```
echo "Creating data"
Rscript create_data.R 5000000
wc -l data.csv

echo "Testing R"
time Rscript cut.R

echo "Testing Spark"
time spark-submit cut.py
```

**Output of the tests:**

```
$ . run_test.sh
Creating data
5000001 data.csv
Testing R
          dates  ids sales  categories
1264 2010-01-01 ID10    60 Category 01

real    0m12.689s
user    0m12.498s
sys     0m0.187s
Testing Spark
[u'2010-01-01', u'"ID10"', u'60', u'"Category 01"']

real    0m17.029s
user    0m7.388s
sys     0m0.392s
```

I am running this on a Ubuntu in a VirtualBox with Windows 7 as host system, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Spark is a distributed computing framework and it's model is to break down the work in pieces (tasks), where those tasks are scheduled, serialized and shipped based on the DAG derived from the dependencies in the functional transformations defined on the RDD.

All that machinery comes with an overhead cost, even in local mode. When compared to R, it is not unexpected that R, having been designed for single node execution will work faster.

Try the same comparison on a cluster... oh... wait... R only runs in a single node [(but not for long anymore)](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/09/announcing-sparkr-r-on-spark.html).

Comment: But shouldn't Spark still parallelize the operation? Since R is not parallelized I expected Spark to show an improvement. But maybe sorting is just the wrong job to run as a test?